# Render bmp images in org mode

Tags: org-mode, images

I want to quickly embed images in an `org` document and am trying to use [`org-download`](https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download) to help me.  However, due to [a silly bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1191462), images are saved as `.bmp` files.  The result is that `org-download` embeds a `.bmp` which Emacs can't render.

I see three ways to solve this problem:

1. Fix Firefox
2. Configure Emacs to render `.bmp` files
3. Convert the saved files to `.png` or other format

Option 2 seems simplest.

So, how can I render `.bmp` images in Emacs?

I am using GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2019-04-13, obtained directly from [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), on Windows 10.  It seems that one method to display `.bmp` files is to [use `imagemagick`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/ImageMagick-Images.html).  I have `imagemagick` installed and on my path.  Unfortunately, `(image-type-available-p 'imagemagick)` is `nil`, which I take to mean the GnuEmacs .exe was not compiled with `imagemagick` support.  I have configured Emacs to work with `.png` files, having installed the appropriate `png` dll.  I wonder, could the problem be solved similarly, i.e. via a `libbmp.dll`?  I could not find any such library.

Or, am I too far down [the XY rabbit hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?  Is there a different approach which will allow me to quickly embed images in an `org` document?